# How to get a radio button value without defining a new route in Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, python-decorators

I have the following HTML code:

```
<form action="/Team" method="post">
    <label>Choose team:</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="FirstTeam" name="HattrickTeams" value="{{user_data['team 1 id']}}" checked>
    <label for="FirstTeam">{{user_data['team 1 name']}}</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="SecondTeam" name="HattrickTeams" value="{{user_data['team 2 id']}}">
    <label for="SecondTeam">{{user_data['team 2 name']}}</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="ThirdTeam" name="HattrickTeams" value="{{user_data['team 3 id']}}">
    <label for="ThirdTeam">{{user_data['team 3 name']}}</label><br>
    <input type="submit" id="SubmitButton" value="OK">
</form>
```

I need to get the value of the selected radio button. I did this using the following code:

```
team_id = request.form['HattrickTeams']
```

The problem is I don't want to use a route, as I saw in other similar questions. I want to use `team_id` for backend purposes. Plus, a function used as a route decorator needs to return a value and I don't want that, because there is none.

How can I get the value of a radio button without using a route decorator?

Comment: You want to get the value when the form is submitted? Thus you have to handle the request to `/Team` somewhere, which needs a route.

Comment: @Erich I want to get this value, to use it download an XML file. The XML file I will parse it and the data from it will be in a list box, which is in the same page as the above form. This is why I don't want to use a route.

Comment: Do you already have a route for `/Team`? If yes, you can just check if the request is a `POST` request and check for the data, then download the `XML` file and put the data in a list box and serve the same page again.

Comment: @Erich looks like a sensible idea. Let's see how it goes. And yes, I have a route for `/Team`

Comment: Did the approach work?

Comment: Yes. You may write an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a `route` for `'/Team'`, you can check there if the request is a `POST` request to process the data from the form, e.g.

```
@app.route('/Team', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        data = flask.request.values.get('data') # retrieve data from post request
        # process data, store in database, etc.
    else:
        # render form without data, etc.
```

That way you don't have to add an additional route.